# dataTables, call jquery ajax to click in column

Tags: jquery, database

I need to put a column in the data row with a button or image when the user clicks, an ajax call. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of the table cells, insert the HTML markup required for a button.  Each button should have a global class attribute and an unique ID.

Bind a click listener to the button class and use the button ID for row-specific actions.